# I need to create a smart phone application that could be run on all smart phones, How can i do this?

Tags: java, android, ios, cross-platform, mobile-phones

What is the programming language for every operating system?

Comment: iphone - objective C, android - java, blackberry..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [cross-platform development for mobile devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380196/cross-platform-development-for-mobile-devices)

Answer (score 3):

There is no single technology, that will let you write the application once for all of them.

There are several causes here:

1. Every platform has it's own architecture and libraries for doing common things such as gui, hardware access and so on.
2. Most of them use different languages. iPhone uses Objective-C, Java is for Android, so on.
3. There was a try - J2ME technology, but it doesn't seem to have rich abilities foreach of the platform.

The only thing you can try is an HTML5 application(which uses web browser). But it makes sence only if you don't need access to some native abilities of the handset - camera, contact list and so on.

Answer (score 1):

[PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) is a technology that promises to assist you in writing cross platform applications.

Answer (score 1):

Write a fancy web application. All modern smartphones have an up-to-date webbrowser.  If you look at the mobile-web versions of GMail and calendar, they look almost native.

It's the most cross-phone way you'll find.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Phonegap which will allow you to package a web app to look like an app which is the closest you can get to this unicorn currently

To really mimick an application look and feel you will need to use something like Jquery Mobile or Sencha touch unfortunately these javascript frameworks will not run on all modern phones and the phonegap approach does not currently work for WP7

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. Windows Phone 7 for example can only be programmed using Silverlight and is bound to the .NET Framework, which is not available for iPhone and Android in a fully functional version. Java (Android) will not be available on iPhone and Windows Phone 7. This list could go on and on... I'd consider creating a web application.

Answer (score 0):

If you write a web app, just keep in mind, that you don't have access to parts of the hardware, which you would have using the native SDKs.